# Run a Bash Command on File Change?

Tags: macos, bash, unix

My question is how can I run a Bash command on some file change?

For example, if I am writing a C program and every time the file is saved I run the command `rm output; gcc program.c -o output; ./output` automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [inotifywait](http://www.kodkast.com/unix-command/inotifywait) for this specific purpose.

```
while true; do
  change=$(inotifywait -e close_write,moved_to,create .)
  change=${change#./ * }
  if [ "$change" = "program.c" ]; then rm output; gcc program.c -o output; ./output; fi
done
```

Comment: I wish I could use this... but unfortunately I'm on mac

Answer (score 3):

You could use `make` and `watch`:

Makefile:

```
output: program.c
        gcc program.c -o output
        ./output
```

then

```
$ watch make
```

in a separate terminal.

However, there will be a small delay between when you save program.c and when it gets run.

Comment: This is cool. It really approaches exactly the functionality I was looking for and I can imagine an easy way to use this method to watch for last mod time.